# JavaScript load a file not from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I have this function to read a text file from a specific location:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function readTextFile(file){
        var out_text=''
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function (){
          if(rawFile.readyState === 4){
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0){
              var allText = rawFile.responseText;
              out_text=allText;
            }
          }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
        return out_text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="file_txt"></div>
    <script>
      txt = readTextFile('http://arbsq.net/dchampolu/champolu_data.txt');
      document.getElementById("file_txt").innerHTML=txt;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The thing is that I want to read a text file that continuously changes:
http://arbsq.net/dchampolu/champolu_data.txt

when I run this function once, the browser caches the text file, and then every time I run the code, it only gets the cached version, not the updated version.

I can always tell the users to clean this cache and this sort of stuff, but is there a way by JavaScript or jQuery to force the browser to use only the current version of the file, not the cached version?

Comment: hey you have to add some dummy random number in the end of ajax url
eg: http://arbsq.net/dchampolu/champolu_data.txt?123456

Comment: looks like a smart solution, I'll try it, can you post it as an answer so that I accept it :)

Comment: it is good, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for dummy random number you can use timestamp too
eg: `'http://arbsq.net/dchampolu/champolu_data.txt?' + (new Date()).getTime()`

Answer (score 5):

You can set up the server to tell the client not to cache the file or you can use a cache buster in the url.
For cache busting just add a query string with a unique value at the end

```
rawFile.open("GET", file+'?dc='+(new Date()).getTime(), false);
```